# Create boot.img from compiled kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, magisk

I am trying to install Magisk on a RePhone. The only operating system related download I found (on the company's website or anywhere else) is this: https://myrephone.com/opensource.7z

That seems to be the kernel source, so if I understand it right, that should be roughly what I need to obtain `boot.img`. I have compiled an Android system before and afterwards the file just existed and I could use it, but here it doesn't. Is it possible to create that file from the compiled result? If yes, how?

Some more background: Not much development work seems to have been done on this phone model so far, so I can't just install LineageOS or TWRP. The stock recovery doesn't allow full ADB, only sideloading, so I can't run arbitrary commands on the phone, like extracting `boot.img` from it. The bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: I don't have enough rep. to create a "rephone" tag, but I think it would be useful, because it's a totally separate model and even manufacturer. Could someone please do that?

Comment: Tag created. Please suggest a tag wiki edit, otherwise [the tag will be removed after 6 months if it's only used on 1 question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/241919).